# How to speed up JUnit Tests in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, junit

In an ant based java project in Netbeans, unit tests take for ever to complete. How do I spead up the unit tests. Eclipse runs the same tests quite fast and same is the case on the command-line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

- Open the netbeans options window.
- Go to Java -> Ant tab.
- Add a new property `junit.forkmode=once`.

Apply and rerun the tests, you'll notice the tests run significantly faster.
For more detail about for attribute please read.

[Running junit from ant beware the fork attribute](http://blog.nominet.org.uk/tech/2007/07/06/running-junit-from-ant-beware-the-fork-attribute/)

This may cause Permgen space problem. To fix that add a vm argument in the project properties dialog box.

`-Xms128m -Xmx1536m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m`

[image]

#### How significant is the improvement ?

Here are the results for a project with 11,751 unit tests.

**Test run without the junit.forkmode**

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 40 minutes 17 seconds
```

**Test run with junit.forkmode=once**

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 4 minutes 31 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Not specific to ant, rather than a general suggestion:

- Use SSD
- Download the latest Netbeans
- Remove all the plugins you don't need
- Use the latest version of Java
- Specifically for every project - remove unused jars (worth reviewing
  your target dependency tree from time to time)